# Simple algebraic question: homework

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two boats, Boat A and Boat B, leave a boat dock, with Boat B departing 15 minutes after Boat A. Boat A maintained a constant speed of 15 miles per hour while traveling the 10-mile distance across the lake, while Boat B maintained a constant speed of 25 miles per hour over the same route. At what mile location of the route did Boat B pass Boat A?

Comment: You should post some of your own insights or attempts before asking a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

If we let $t$ denote the time in hours after departure, Boat A left at time $t = 0.25$. The boats have speeds of 15 miles per hour (Boat A) and 25 miles per hour (Boat B). Equationally, we can represent these as

- $f_A(t) = 15t + (0.25 \cdot 15)$
- $f_B(t) = 25t$

where $f_A(t),f_B(t)$ represent the distance traveled in miles. The coefficients of $t$ are the rates of travel, and the constant for $f_A(t)$ denotes the "head start" Boat A got (a quarter hour, at 15 mph).

Your goal is to find when Boat A and B had their paths cross. Equationally, this would be when $f_A(t) = f_B(t)$, assuming that $f_A(t),f_B(t)$ are between $[0,10]$. You're then asked to figure out at which location this crossover happened; this would correspond to plugging the $t$ into an equation to get the distance.